# How to put variable in `pyodbc` query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am using `pyodbc` to save data in Microsoft SQL Server.

I 3 string variables, `user_first_name`, `user_last_name` and `profile_photo_path`

```
user_first_name = 'Shams'
user_last_name = 'Nahid'
file_name = 'my_profile_photo_path'
```

Now when I try to save data using

```
cursor.execute(f'''
                    INSERT INTO pyUser.dbo.user_information (first_name, last_name, profile_photo_path)
                    VALUES
                    ({user_first_name}, {user_last_name}, {file_name})

                    ''')
```

I get the following error

> Invalid column name \'Shams\'.
>
> Invalid column name \'Nahid\'.
>
> The multi-part identifier "directory.PNG" could not be bound.

But instead of the variable, if I put the hardcoded string

```
cursor.execute('''
                    INSERT INTO pyUser.dbo.user_information (first_name, last_name, profile_photo_path)
                    VALUES
                    ('my_user_first_name', 'my_user_last_name', 'my_file_name')

                    ''')
```

Then the query shows no error.

I checked the variable type, `user_first_name`, `user_last_name` and `file_name`, all are `<class 'str'>`

How can I put the variable in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using string formatting to insert column values into an SQL statement is a dangerous practice because it exposes your code to *SQL Injection* vulnerabilities. For example, the code in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54166425/2144390) will work for

```python
user_last_name = "Nahid"
```

but it will fail for

```python
user_last_name = "O'Connor"
```

SQL injection can also have serious security implications. Perform a web search for "Little Bobby Tables" to see an example of that.

Rather, you should use a *parameterized query* like so:

```python
user_first_name = 'Shams'
user_last_name = 'Nahid'
file_name = 'my_profile_photo_path'

sql = '''\
INSERT INTO pyUser.dbo.user_information (first_name, last_name, profile_photo_path)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
'''
params = (user_first_name, user_last_name, file_name, )
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Answer (score 1):

I try again, it is work, for example

```
import pymysql

def test():
    db = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '****', 'python')
    cur = db.cursor()
    id_ = "123456"
    query = ''.join(["select *", " from customer where id = ", id_])
    cur.execute(query)
    result = cur.fetchone()
    print("result: ", result)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by putting a quotation on both sides of the variable.

```
cursor.execute(f'''
                    INSERT INTO pyUser.dbo.user_information (first_name, last_name, profile_photo_path)
                    VALUES
                    ('{user_first_name}', '{user_last_name}', '{file_name}')

                    ''')
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try this

```
cursor.execute('''
                    INSERT INTO pyUser.dbo.user_information (first_name, last_name, profile_photo_path)
                    VALUES
                    ("Shams", "Nahid", "my_profile_photo_path")

                    ''')
```