# The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'

Tags: python, sql-server

I wrote with python as want to select element in table in SQL but it show as below, 
Could you please help what's wrong.
thanks,

```
### Connect to server and select element:

sql='''SELECT top 10 * FROM Doan_LabelcodeFruPP' where Model = ?'''
Model = conn.cursor()
Model.execute(sql,var)
var = (Model,)
Model.execute(sql,var)

result = Model.fetchone()
if result is not None:
    print('Success:',result)
else:
    print('No row found for', result)
```

Comment: what is this ' after the Doan_LabelcodeFruPP

Comment: Also please supply the error message in your initial post.

Comment: look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166278/how-to-put-variable-in-pyodbc-query looks like it should be this:
sql='''\SELECT top 10 * FROM Doan_LabelcodeFruPP where Model = ?'''

Comment: Hi Marx, ArunasB, Doan_LabelcodeFruPP is a name of table. and I want to show a element in :Model" column of tabel.  """ Errorr showed: ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')"""

Comment: my code as below: import pyodbc 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=yRecTrack;UID=Sa;PWD=password')


sql='''SELECT top 10 * FROM Doan_LabelcodeFruPP' where Model = ?'''

Model = conn.cursor()
Model.execute(sql,var)
var = (Model,)
Model.execute(sql,var)

result = Model.fetchone()
if result is not None:
    print('Success:',result)
else:
    print('No row found for', result)